# How to generate seperate request by loop method & using beanshell preporcessor

Tags: loops, jmeter, beanshell

Can some one help me out for solution.

Objective/Issue: In Jmeter search by subject name request need to pass the variable "subjName" from BeanshellPreProcessor.
"subjName" This variable is having list of subjects which are being sent to "search by subject request"
My object is to send the subject separately & FOR EACH SUBJECT A NEW REQUEST SHOULD BE GENERATED.

Bean shell script is as follows

[image: BeanShell]

and the search by subject name [image]

Please suggest me the logic/script how can I generate different request for different subject?

Comment: what is your current state? are you send 1 request? what's the loop condition?

Comment: Currently it is sending 1 request & only latest subject name is displayed on GUI. I want to generate separate request for each subject name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define loop with loop count 9

Add a Counter: Start: 0 Increment: 1 Maximum: 8 Reference Name: cnt

Inside beanshell use `vars.get("cnt")` instead of variable i (you don't need the loop inside beanshell)

Comment: Can u please elaborate little more! I am not getting what value to set as reference variable for Counter, bean shell script & reference variable in search request ?

Comment: I have changed the implementation , replaced the beanshell from Foreach loop controller.